# Android sendBroadcast() followed by finish()

Tags: java, android, thread-safety

I am stuck on something that seems to be a thread synchronization problem.
I have two classes:

`AppLayout that extends Activity
SettingsPart that extends Fragment and implements some Listeners`

When the settings are applied successfully I would like to send a Broadcast and finish the Activity, so the code in SettingsPart.java looks like:

`((AppLayout) getActivity()).sendBroadcast(intent);
((AppLayout) getActivity()).finish();`

The Activity closes as expected, but no broadcast is sent.
If I remove the call to finish() the broadcast is sent successfully.

Is there any smart way to wait for the broadcast to be sent before closing the activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Activity is receiving the broadcast, it just can't do anything with it (because the activity is finishing immediately). Instead of calling finish() SettingsPart.java, I would call finish() from wherever you're processing the broadcast within the Activity. Just be careful that you finish the activity in all cases and don't leave it unfinished forever.

Comment: The broadcast will be received by a Service and I need to wait for it to be send before I can close my Activity. One Idea would be to have another Intent sent from the Service to close the Activity when it received the broadcast, but this looks as an 'ugly' solution for me.